# How Forces are Represented from Quantum Computation or Entanglement Perspective?

Tags: forces, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-computer, interactions

In the fields of Quantum Computation and [Entanglement](http://qpt.physics.harvard.edu/simons/Swingle.pdf) there is content on the structure of quantum systems and artificial quantum systems like qubits and quantum cellular automata. I have even seen the computation/information interpretation of quantum mechanics applied to light and fundamental particles. However, I haven't seen anything on *forces* as interpreted from an quantum computation perspective. Wondering if there exists any research in this area.

Specifically I am wondering about gravity, electromagnetism, and the strong and weak force modeled from a discretized Quantum Computation or Entanglement perspective, if one exists. If nothing exists, wondering what the closest would be.

I'm wondering because forces carry some sort of information, and it causes things to happen, so there must be some information associated with it. In looking at diagrams like the one below, I am having a hard time imagining how the force could be described from an quantum computational perspective.

[image]

Comment: How are forces modelled in classical information theory? How interactions arise and are modelled is certainly part of quantum mechanics, but those are not the questions that quantum information is concerned with. Your question is a bit like asking how does literary criticism deal with sculpture or how does marine biology deal with horses. It is simply a different field

Comment: reformulating physics in different types of mathematical machinery used in different areas of physics is something that should be pursued actively without expecting approval. It might even lead to interesting insights that those that complain cannot imagine. +1